# Adobe Brackets and running Ruby/Python programs

Tags: python, ruby, sublimetext2, adobe-brackets

so I have been trying out various text editors and IDE's recently to see what I like. I really like the web developer side of Brackets, which is what I think it was designed for, but was also messing around with some of the extensions for building and running Python/Ruby programs.

I have tried this, which honestly doesn't seem to do anything from what I can tell:
https://github.com/vhornets/brackets-builder

And this, which adds a run button to Brackets for running the program:
https://github.com/jadbox/brackets-integrated-development

The latter seems to work alright... until you make a small program that asks for user input then the program never runs, the program disappears, and then you have to restart Brackets to get it back. The code I have used is the following:

```
puts"Please enter your name: "
n = gets. chomp
```

Or

```
n = input("Please enter your name: ")
```

Any idea what might be causing this? I asked the developer, but haven't heard back. I'd probably use Brackets exclusively if it wasn't for that issue.

Tried Sublime Text 3 for a little while, but didn't like the lack of a Brackets like live preview plugin. However, it looks like it runs Python/Ruby (in addition to Java and C/C++) code without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try a generic extension for running command line tools, such as one of these:

- [Command Line Shortcuts](https://github.com/antivanov/Brackets-Command-Line-Shortcuts)
- [Brackets Build System](https://github.com/aymanizz/Brackets-Build-Systems)
- [Command Runner](https://github.com/tarcisiojr/brackets-command-runner)
- [Brackets Shell access](https://github.com/johnhidey/hdy.brackets-shell/)
- [Brackets Terminal](https://github.com/artoale/brackets-terminal)
- The [Brackets Builder](https://github.com/Vhornets/brackets-builder) you mentioned above - looks like you choose *Edit > Edit Builder* to configure the commands you want, and then you can press Ctrl-Alt-B to run them.

Comment: Bracket Builder didn't work, little fix to make it working: https://github.com/nuriyevn/brackets-builder

Answer (score 1):

[Brackets Builder](https://github.com/Vhornets/brackets-builder) has worked best for me "*right out of the box*". However, I run into the same problem as you (when wanting to perform console inputs) in both Brackets AND Sublime, but NOT in [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html).

A good clean work around inside Brackets, for when you need to test programs with console inputs, is to load the extension "[Open project in terminal](https://github.com/ranjandatta/brackets-open-in-linux-terminal)", which will allow you to open a terminal right from your current project folder and run your python script. This allowed me to run your case from Brackets with very little hassle, and of course, it works great in a real terminal.

To make this approach even easier, I've asked the developers on GitHub, thru a raised [**issue**](https://github.com/ranjandatta/brackets-open-in-linux-terminal/issues/4), if they can add support for more terminal programs in Windows, such as ConEmu, and if they could allow intial command line arguments to be loaded, which would make this type of work that you want to do even more seamless and fast. I'll update my post once I see any improvements or alternatives to all the above points.